# Given a satisfactory real number = [any integer]/(2b) where a and b are integers, how would one find the minimum value of b?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, optimization

For instance, `0.625 = 5/(2*4)`. Given 0.625, how would one find 4?

`0.75 = 1/(2*2)`. Given 0.75, how would one find 2?

I should clarify that I don't care about the value of a. I am just trying to find the minimum positive integer value of b given that n = [any integer]/(2b).

I need the answer in the form that can easily be used in Python code, rather than the forms which can easily be done by hand but are messier in code.

Comment: You need to have some extra condition or you just can know the value of the ratio $\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: I should clarify that I don't care about the value of a. I am just trying to find the minimum positive integer value of b given that n = (an integer)/(2b). Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have meant rational decimal fraction instead of real numbers

Convert the decimal fraction to  vulgar fraction $=\dfrac pq$(say).

If gcd$(p,q)=d,$  divide the numerator & the denominator by $d$

If the denominator remains even, we are done

Else multiply the numerator & the denominator by $2$

Comment: I appreciate the response. This method seems like it may work reasonably, although it doesn't play that nicely with use from code. Would you happen to be able to rearrange it into a form that does, preferably without fractions? Don't worry if not, I can probably work something out with this.

Answer (score 0):

$$
0.625=\frac{625}{1000}=\frac{5^4}{2^35^3}=\frac5{2^3}=\frac5{2\cdot4}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. While I can see how this works in this specific instance, is there any way to express this as a single equation rather than a method? I need to be able to use this in Python code on arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you are asking for an integer b which will satisfy the condition a/b =1.25.
1.25 = 125/100 = 5/4 
simplify until you don't have common factors in the denominator and the numerator.

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm being super dumb right now(totally possible) I don't think this actually solves the problem. I have amended the question and title a little to add detail and clarify that a is merely a place-holder for any integer value. Sorry for my incompetence.

Answer (score 0):

- If the last digit is 5, keep doubling until it is not (or it is an integer).
- If the last digit is even, keep multiplying by 5 until it is not (or it is an integer).
- If the last digit is 1,3,7 or 9, keep multiplying by 10 until it is an integer.